# Create data pipeline in C

Tags: c, algorithm

My idea is to create a 2 stage pipeline with global time clock (100 cycles). The two stages are represented as two functions and are the following: The first one generates 2D random matrix - once generated this data is moved to stage two, and immediately stage 1 starts generating new data. Meanwhile stage 2 sums the 2D matrix and provides an output. This movement/computation is repeated for the 100 cycles.

Do I utilize a local iteration of 100 cycles for each function. I don't want to use a fork/pipe option.

I have used the following but it generates sequentially:

```
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    stage_one();
    stage_two();
    }
```

The other option is to locally do the loop for each stage and use data queue to move between functions.

Can someone introduce me to a resource I can read/test how to do it. I thank you very much for your help.

Comment: thread + queue of data?

Comment: Do your functions use global variables to store the state? Then firstly rewrite them to store state using local variables. Then use `pthread` to create one thread for each pipeline.

Comment: Kamil - yes they are with global variales.  Pthreads - I will try with it. Thank you.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - would omp threads and queues be sufficient?

Comment: @newbie_new sure! One would be the producer the other the consumer. Look at producer/consumer pattern in multithreading.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thank you very much for your guidance. I will check it out. I assume the producer/consumer pattern could involve more than 2 stages am I right in this assumption?

Comment: It's a matter of organization. You can have one producer with multiple consumers as well as multiple producers with one consumers etc. More than two stages sound more like "chaining" producer/consumer so that 1st stage consumer is as well 2nd stage producer. However, it's worth to keep the hardware concurrency in mind. There will not be true concurrency with more threads than CPU cores (although the OS is able to manage pseudo concurrency for more threads/processes).

Comment: I would strongly recommend against trying to implement your idea in C.  The issues around correct synchronization, avoiding race conditions, and so on make it a poor choice of language for your purposes.  Instead I would suggest that you either use Go (which makes your design easy), or else simplify life with a single-thread approach.